# RandomGenerator for multidimensional array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.x = [[2.5, 0, -0.5]]
```

I have writing a randNumberGenerator as follows, how do I use it to replace scope.x as it is above?

```
function randomNumberGenerator(){
    var chartData =[[]];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var y = Math.round(Math.random() * (-3 + i / 2))  + i/10;
        console.log(y)
        chartData.push({
            y:y
        });
    }

    this.get_x = function () {
        return chartData;
    }
}
```

Comment: structure being returned from function is different than original array. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

According to how you have written your generator, you need to create an instance of it and then call method `get_x`:

```
$scope.x = new randomNumberGenerator().get_x();
```

However, it would make sense to just use simple function, not a constructor:

```
function randomNumberGenerator(){
    var chartData = [[]];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var y = Math.round(Math.random() * (-3 + i / 2))  + i/10;
        console.log(y)
        chartData.push({
            y:y
        });
    }

    return chartData;
}
```

and then

```
$scope.x = randomNumberGenerator();
```